# Why some programs are able to edit /etc/hosts while others are not?

Tags: unix, vim, emacs, editor, hosts

I tried to edit my **/etc/hosts** file using Emacs, VSCode, etc. (with sudo, of course) and it kept saying that I did not have the permissions to edit the file.

Then I tried with Vim, Nano and Atom... and those were able to edit and save the file.

(Running `echo 'some host' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts` has also worked just fine).

So why is that? Why some editors can edit the file without any problem while others don't?

Comment: `sudo /usr/bin/emacs /etc/hosts` works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open `C-x C-f /sudo::/etc/hosts` with your local emacs.

Comment: That did work, thanks. But why doesn't it work with just `sudo emacs file`, like with vim?

Comment: As said by @choroba, `sudo emacs /etc/hosts` works for me as well. It doesn't seem to be an Emacs issue, likely it is related to your local sudoers config or so,

Answer (score 0):

I can not really provide the answer, but I'm sure about one thing: you should avoid starting Emacs in sudo-mode!

Using `/sudo::/etc/hosts` as mentioned in the other answer is one option, but I prefer to use `sudo -e /etc/hosts` since that is even safer and can be run from the command-line. That will open a copy of the file in the default editor and save it back when it's closed.

To set the default editor to Emacs execute `export EDITOR=emacsclient` beforehand (I'm assuming here you have started the emacs-server). This setting is a good idea anyway, since it works with many other command-line tools, so you should put it in your shell initialization config.

Usually I've a shell alias for `e` to open a normal file with `emacsclient` and `E` to open it via `sudo -e`, which is easy to remember.